# When we mustn't declare function inline(GCC compiler)?

Tags: c++, gcc

I need to write a program that finds out the restrictions of the usage of inline functions.

I found following information for GCC compiler(http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html#Inline):

Note that certain usages in a function definition can make it unsuitable for inline substitution. Among these usages are: variadic functions, use of alloca, use of computed goto (see Labels as Values), use of nonlocal goto, use of nested functions, use of setjmp, use of __builtin_longjmp and use of __builtin_return or __builtin_apply_args. Using -Winline warns when a function marked inline could not be substituted, and gives the reason for the failure.

Then i wrote following program with variadic function:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline double average(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    double sum = 0;

    va_start(ap, count);

    for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        /* Increments ap to the next argument. */
        sum += va_arg(ap, int);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return sum / count;
}  

int main(void) {
    cout << average(4,6,8,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

And then compiled my program like this: `g++ -Wall -Winline program.cpp`.
After compilation there was no warning from `-Winline`.

What i did wrong? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the page you linked:

> GCC does not inline any functions when not optimizing

Adding -O2 to the commandline produces the following warnings in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/68aBlY):

```
<source>: In function 'double average(int, ...)':
<source>:6:15: warning: function 'double average(int, ...)' can never be inlined because it uses variable argument lists [-Winline]

 inline double average(int count, ...)   
               ^~~~~~~

<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:6:15: warning: inlining failed in call to 'double average(int, ...)': function not inlinable [-Winline]
<source>:23:30: note: called from here
     cout << average(4,6,8,2,3);

                              ^
```